# How to login to a website using selenium in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to this website using my credentials. However, although I'm providing what they have in their html, it's not working

Currently, I have

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = './chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

LOGIN_PAGE = "https://www.seekingalpha.com/login"
ACCOUNT = "account.com"
PASSWORD = "password"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})

driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
username.send_keys(ACCOUNT)
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button._60b46-2mbi1 _60b46-2LbhQ _60b46-1HfKK _60b46-qZydf _60b46-1uOHx _60b46-2NDcV _60b46-3YvwX _60b46-22lGb _60b46-1qE-_ _60b46-3DOuR _60b46-1UPRS _12b23-2JWwg _60b46-EQJB_")
submit_button.click()


driver.get("https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414043-agenus-inc-agen-ceo-garo-armen-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript")
text_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*')

text = text_element

for t in text:
    print(t.text)
```

and I keep getting

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="email"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved with the help of explicit wait. See the code below :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\etc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys("some user name")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "signInPasswordField"))).send_keys("your password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Sign in']"))).click()
print("Logged in")
```

Read more about explicit wait [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to wait after going to the URL for the element to appear, instead of trying immediately to identify it. You could add it like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# all of your current code

driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element_by_name("email")))

username.send_keys(ACCOUNT)

# rest of your code
```

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely clear from the code you showing that you are missing wait / delay between

```
driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
```

and the

```
driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
```

lines.  So, you can simply add

```
time.sleep(3)
```

there or if you wish to make it properly use something like

```
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element_by_name("email")))
```

as already mentioned by C.Peck